# I am having trouble with TDD with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, tdd

I am trying to write a test for a new function that I want to add.  However, when I run the test the project won't build for a completely unrelated reason.  A normal build works fine. As you can see below, the errors are stating that the struct WeatherDataOutput is not declared.  It is declared.  The test class is empty.  I'm not sure why I'm getting this error in Xcode.  I restarted Xcode and I cleaned the project, but nothing is working for me.  I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

[image: A struct in it's own swift file]

[image: Test code]

[image: Errors from a struct]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Post text as text.

Comment: I wanted to show the error messages.  There is nothing wrong with my code.  It builds fine.  Just not for test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've cleaned everything, then perform build for testing, sometimes the build succeeds and an error still shows in the source code interface which shouldn't be there.  It's a bug in Xcode.

When this happens: put your cursor at the end of the offending line and hit enter, then delete (add a new line then remove it).

I've had to do this countless times in my own projects.  Really, just modifying the offending line slightly then changing it back is the idea.  New lines at the beginning or end of the offending line seems to be most effective in my experience.

**OR**

Remove the AppDataStorage source file from your test target.

Comment: This solution doesn't work.  Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @gfgruvin Your project successfully builds using Command-B right?  Does it successfully build using Command-Shift-U?

Comment: @gfgruvin I just realized the 3rd picture you posted is not your test case class...  Select the file where AppDataStorage is and make sure the right hand Utilities pane is open.  Under "Target Membership," is your test target checked?

Comment: Project builds using cmd-B but not cmd-shift-U.  The test target is checked for the file containing AppDataStorage.

Comment: I just removed the test target from the file containing AppDataStorage and now the project is building with cmd-shift-U.  Xcode adds all of the source files to the test target.  Thank for your help

Comment: @gfgruvin 3rd time is the charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you want `AppDataStorage` in a separate file in your test suite, add the `import WeatherDemoApp` to that file.  If the file also contains a test case class, use `@testable import WeatherDemoApp`

Comment: I do have @testable import WeatherDemoApp at the top of my test class.

Comment: I'm trying to TDD a new function that doesn't even reference that struct.  AppDataStorage is in a separate file in my project.  I am not even trying to test with anything in that file. This error makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally added that file to the test target instead of your apps target?  Check the utility pane for the `AppDataStorage` file and make sure the proper target is checked.

Comment: Ok according to your other comment, you have the wrong Target checked.  Since that file isn't being used in your test target, uncheck that, and check the box for your app.